# Subtracting 2 dimensional-arrays with a unique id column

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, enumerable

I'd like to subtract two 2 dimensional-arrays, optionally by placing attention on a "unique id" column.

Also curious about a more description way to say what I'm looking for.

But, for example, given two arrays:

```
big = [['foo','bar@','baz'],
       ['cat','moew@','purr'],
       ['dog','bark@','woof'],
       ['mew', 'two@', 'blue']]

little = [['foo','bar@','baz'],
          ['dog','moew@','woof'],
          ['dog','bark@','woof']]
```

Then we can subtract them:

```
big - little #=> [["cat", "moew@", "purr"], ["mew", "two@", "blue"]]
```

Which works because `['cat','moew@','purr'] != ['dog','moew@','woof']`. However, I'd like those two to be considered equal because they have the same value in the "unique id" column.

This is how I solved it:

```
big = [['foo','bar@','baz'],
       ['cat','moew@','purr'],
       ['dog','bark@','woof'],
       ['mew', 'two@', 'blue']]

little = [['foo','bar@','baz'],
          ['dog','moew@','woof'],
          ['dog','bark@','woof']]


def subtract big, little, key_index=nil
  return big - little unless key_index
  little_keys = little.map { |row| row[key_index] }.flatten
  big.inject([]) do |result, row|
    result << row unless little_keys.grep(row[key_index]).any?
    result
  end
end

subtract(big,little) #=> [["cat", "moew@", "purr"], ["mew", "two@", "blue"]]
subtract(big, little, 1) #=> [["mew", "two@", "blue"]]
```

Am curious to know more about how to describe what I'm trying to do and if there is a better way to do it.

Also, is my way `O(n^2)` because it's going through the entire array twice? Once for the `#inject` and once for `#grep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on a bus and cannot type code easily. If you have unique ids, you could convert the 2D array to a hash with unique id as key and array as value.

```
big = { 'bar@' => ['foo','bar@','baz'], ...
```

The data you want should be something like `big.values_at(*(big.keys-little.keys))`

Comment: Is it better to use because there aren't any nested loops?

Comment: Yes, it should be O(n) instead of O(n**2)

Comment: +1 thank you @EricDuminil will upvote later today. Updated [here](https://github.com/mbigras/liffy_diffy/blob/fa855683d7752d8f02d841c1d3de8489d5a6863b/lib/liffy_diffy/differ.rb#L14-L34) if you're interested :)

Comment: BTW, you want to use each_with_object instead of inject and returning the same object every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
big = [['foo','bar@','baz'],
       ['cat','moew@','purr'],
       ['dog','bark@','woof'],
       ['mew', 'two@', 'blue']]

little = [['foo','bar@','baz'],
          ['foo','bark@','baz'],
          ['dog','moew@','woof'],
          ['dog','bark@','woof']]
```

Note I've changed `little` from the example in the question.

```
require 'set'

little_set = little.each_with_object(Set.new) { |(_,u,_), set| set << u }
  #=> #<Set: {"bar@", "bark@", "moew@"}>

big.reject { |_,m,_| little_set.include?(m) }
  #=> [["mew", "two@", "blue"]]
```

Comment: Nice. Your solution is probably faster since it creates fewer objects.

Comment: You could use an index instead of hardcoding the array structure, though.